# IIS 8 Hosting Error (503 Service Unavailable)

Tags: asp.net, iis

I host the site web site on IIS 8. It's develop by using VS 2013.

Site is working fine. After 1,2 days got the following error when browsing the site "503 Service Unavailable".

After restarting the server site is working. But once again got the above error withing 1, 2 hours.

These are the errors on the server Event Viewer log.

Error 1. 
An unhandled win32 exception occurred in w3wp.exe [2960]. Just-In-Time debugging this exception failed with the following error: Debugger could not be started because no user is logged on.

Check the documentation index for 'Just-in-time debugging, errors' for more information.

Error 2.
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.0.9200.16384, time stamp: 0x50108835
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.2.9200.17366, time stamp: 0x554d4531
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000000000004aea8
Faulting process id: 0xb90
Faulting application start time: 0x01d10a5f9d0e1b19
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: e4b4ce71-7652-11e5-9402-005056a48cd0
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Error 3
An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.

Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/4/ROOT

Process ID: 2960

Exception: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException

Message: Thread was being aborted.

StackTrace:    at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)

Answer (score 0):

I used NLog for log files.
Get the system log file path, file size are from the config file.
I comment that Log method & It's work fine without any issue.
I think it's may be a security issue.